# How to print random numbers from 2 given arrays without repeating if already printed on ruby

Tags: ruby

lets suppose

```
al=['Al','2l','3l','4l','5l','6l','7l','8l','9l','jl','ql','kl']

af=['Af','2f','3f','4f','5f','6f','7f','8f','9f','jf','qf','kf']

ak=['Ak','2k','3k','4k','5k','6k','7k','8k','9k','jk','qk','kk']

an=['An','2n','3n','4n','5n','6n','7n','8n','9n','jn','qn','kn']
```

are array

let's suppose
there a two-person wait for random numbers to get 
but they should not get the same word ( 3 outputs should be to 2 people from 4 arrays without repeating 
)

Comment: can you give an example of some valid outputs? Also what have you tried?

Comment: Looks like homeworks

Comment: Your title says _"from 2 given arrays"_ but your question says _"from 4 arrays"_. Could you clarify that?

Comment: lets suppose you me and one person are playing card and al=['Al','2l','3l','4l','5l','6l','7l','8l','9l','jl','ql','kl']
af=['Af','2f','3f','4f','5f','6f','7f','8f','9f','jf','qf','kf']
ak=['Ak','2k','3k','4k','5k','6k','7k','8k','9k','jk','qk','kk']
an=['An','2n','3n','4n','5n','6n','7n','8n','9n','jn','qn','kn'] are cards ok so now from those array every peson will get 3 cards but the cards should not be repeted to another person

Comment: To me it looked like random example data. If these arrays represent playing cards for the four suits, you should say so! A practical problem is much easier to understand than an abstract one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Array#sample`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-sample) and then [`Enumerable#each_slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice):

```
persons, cards = 2, 3
(al + af + ak + an).sample(persons * cards).each_slice(cards).to_a
#⇒  [["qk", "4l", "Ak"], ["6l", "8l", "5l"]]
```

Comment: any shortcut  please

Comment: I am not sure I got what you want. I found a time to provide an answer, so find a time to state your question, if any, in readable way.

Comment: lets suppose you me and one person are playing card and al=['Al','2l','3l','4l','5l','6l','7l','8l','9l','jl','ql','kl'] af=['Af','2f','3f','4f','5f','6f','7f','8f','9f','jf','qf','kf'] ak=['Ak','2k','3k','4k','5k','6k','7k','8k','9k','jk','qk','kk'] an=['An','2n','3n','4n','5n','6n','7n','8n','9n','jn','qn','kn'] are cards ok so now from those array every peson will get 3 cards but the cards should not be repeted to another person

Comment: The answer above perfectly solves this particular issue.